# using foreign key in # mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

How can i add foreign key here? Hope you can help me

```
    public bool AddMedicinePrescription(string Generic, string Brand, string ContainerNum, string MedtoStore, string status)
    {
        sqlstring = "INSERT INTO hdmedicine (GenericName, BrandName, ContainerNumber, Quantity,Status )" + "VALUE ('" + Generic + "', '" + Brand + "', " + ContainerNum + ", " + MedtoStore + ", '"+ status +"')";

        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlstring, connect);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            connect.Close();
            return true;
```

Comment: You cannot add a foreign key from an insert statement. You must define the table with a foreign key (or modify it to include one).

Comment: Also Google "SQL Injection"

Comment: what i mean is that i already have foreign key, but i would like to save this datas in two different tables using foreign key.

Comment: you have to do the a separate insert for each table

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** insert into **2 tables** using 1 sql Insert statement.

However, you can use following options

1. Using **[Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386876(v=vs.100).aspx)**, you can create the entities which are linked together. It's much more simpler to perform CRUD (Create, Read, Update & Delete) operation on EF entities as conceptual model is set of classes.
2. Create a stored procedure and insert into 2 tables in the stored procedure.